# Is there a context for corutines that creates new threads up to a limit like a ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to have my application scale a bit automatically if more requests come in, but I would also like to use the non blocking coroutines provided by Kotlin.

Looking though the documentation it seems like the only way to get a Context from the stdlib is to use either [`newSingleThreadContext`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental/new-single-thread-context.html) or [`newFixedThreadPoolContext`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental/new-fixed-thread-pool-context.html) both creating instances of [`ThreadPoolDispacher`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental/-thread-pool-dispatcher/index.html) but that seems to be it.

Is there a way to get something behaving similar to the ThreadPoolExecutor in java that just starts up new threads if currently no thread can take the work up until a given limit for a CoroutineContext in Kotlin? Is this even the right way to thing about Coroutines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn any `Executor` you have into a coroutine context:

```
val MyContext = myExecutor.asCoroutineDispatcher()
```

> Is this even the right way to thing about Coroutines?

This depends more on what you're doing with the coroutines than on what kind of thread pool you're using.

I'm using a cached thread pool, just as you describe it, in my application. It's an Android app so staying slim is important. I use the thread pool both for blocking network ops and for CPU-intensive work that I must do off the GUI thread. In such a use case you don't `launch (MyThreadPool)` your coroutines, but `launch(UI)` and then `withContext(MyThreadPool) { heavyWork }`.

Comment: My workload is on the server side. To be specific its for a discord bot and starts a coroutine for every incoming event. There is no blocking IO happening in the coroutines just light usage of the CPU. The only IO that will happen is non blocking or rather the blocking is done in threads handled by another library.

Comment: Then i wonder how you leverage coroutines. Do you call any `suspend fun`s?

Comment: Not right now but I will. I'm using them more as a easy way to commit jobs to a thread pool in kotlin right now I suppose. But there is another area that is doing a lot of suspending so I will use this there for sure.